# While loop jumps unexpectedly while reading XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading an `XML` file using `XMLDocument` and `XmlNodeReader`.I do not know what happens to the while loop that it fails to run several parts of the code.

Here is my C# code:

```
    public string TitleXml;
    public string NameXml;
    public string TypeXml;
    public string ValueXml;
    public Guid GuidXml;
    public string DataString;


        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(MyParent.xmlstring);        
        XmlNodeReader xreader = new XmlNodeReader(xdoc);           
        while (xreader.Read())
        {
                    switch (xreader.Name)
                    {
                        case"GUID":
                            GuidXml = Guid.Parse(xreader.ReadInnerXml());
                            //after this break the name of the xreader changes.
                            break;

                        case "Type":
                            TypeXml = xreader.ReadInnerXml();
                            break;

                        case "Name":
                            NameXml = xreader.ReadInnerXml();
                            break;

                        case "Title":
                            TitleXml = xreader.ReadInnerXml();
                            break;

                    }
            }
        xreader.Close();            
        }
```

Here is my XML:

```
    <Item>
       <GUID>9A4FA56F-EAA0-49AF-B7F0-8CA09EA39167</GUID>
       <Type>button</Type>
       <Title>Save</Title>
       <Value>submit</Value>
       <Name>btnsave</Name>
       <MaxLen>5</MaxLen>
    </Item>
```

Comment: At what iteration does it break? In other words, what cases does it enter?

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi: It only enters in "GUID" and "Name".

Comment: @Pedram Are you getting any Exception.?

Comment: @RJK:No,no error occurs

Comment: It should be `case "GUID":` instead of `case"GUID":` in your above code. That doesn't solve the issue.I am assuming whether you had properly posted the code or not.

Comment: The code works for me. The only difference is that I pasted the xml to a string instead of reading from a file. And yes, my IDE automatically fixed the missing space.

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi:Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think you should use Linq-to-XML, but for your example I'd explicitly list the elements, like so (compilable example program):

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string xml =
@"<Item>
    <GUID>9A4FA56F-EAA0-49AF-B7F0-8CA09EA39167</GUID>
    <Type>button</Type>
    <Title>Save</Title>
    <Value>submit</Value>
    <Name>btnsave</Name>
    <MaxLen>5</MaxLen>
</Item>";
            XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xml);

            Guid GuidXml = Guid.Parse(elem.Element("GUID").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(GuidXml);

            string TypeXml = elem.Element("Type").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(TypeXml);

            string NameXml = elem.Element("Name").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(NameXml);

            string TitleXml = elem.Element("Title").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(TitleXml);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exactly answer your question, but an (at least according to me) easier way of solving this would be:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

string TitleXml = doc.Descendants("Title").Single().Value;
string NameXml = doc.Descendants("Name").Single().Value;
string TypeXml = doc.Descendants("Type").Single().Value;
string ValueXml = doc.Descendants("Value").Single().Value;
Guid GuidXml = Guid.Parse(doc.Descendants("GUID").Single().Value);
```